# What does ぼうしのどんぐり mean on this page of Yotsuba&!! ?

Tags: grammar, words, manga

I am reading Yotsuba&! manga ch.82, pg.16. Here's the page

[image]

What does the lower left panel `ぼうしのどんぐり` mean? Does it mean acorn which looks like a cap or a cap which looks like acorn (there are caps which look like acorn)? I think it means acorn which look like the caps that Yotsuba has seen before but I am not sure if I am correct. Or does the `ぼうし`here mean something else ?

Manga page source : http://raw.senmanga.com/Yotsubato!/82/16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "acorns with a cap". As you can see in [this link](http://makkurokurosk.blog.so-net.ne.jp/2011-11-14), some acorns you can find in the wild wear a cap, and some don't. She said ぼうしの to only refer to ones with a cap.

～の can mean "wearing ～":

- コートの男 a man in a coat
- 白衣の天使 angels in white (nickname for nurses)
- [とんがり帽子のメモル](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Memole)

Comment: Makes sense now! I couldn't figure that. Thanks : )